# Batteries. Why use 9V?

Tags: batteries

With all the technology available today with being able to boost voltage efficiently using SMPS, why do we still use 9V batteries? Is there some secret advantage with them that I am unaware of?

If you look at the size as well, the 9V is just big and bulky and I have designed projects where I can use 2xAA batteries and boost the voltage, which will give me longer battery life than a 9V. And it takes up the same amount of space.

A lot of circuits today also need regulating, and the easiest way to do that with a 9V is a linear regulator (usually to about 5V) and I am aware this is not the case for every design, but that right there is energy wasted, and yet again, boosting the voltage from 1 or 2 AA batteries will probably give your product a better shelf life.

I saw a comparison between a 9V battery and some AA batteries, where someone found the energy available, and ended up with this data: [image]
**NOTE:** These results were from Energizer Alkaline batteries. The page can be found [HERE](https://www.baldengineer.com/9v-battery-energy-density.html).

So with all this data, why are 9V batteries still used in designs? Are there some applications where it would be advantageous to use them? Or is it usually a better idea just to go for the AA or AAA solution?

There have been times where I have considered using a 9V battery for some of my projects but it always seems after doing my calculations, they just don't hold up as well as others, so am I missing something?

For reference, the datasheets for the compared batteries are here:
[AA](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/e91.pdf)
[9V](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/522.pdf)

**EDIT:** I am not intending this to be an 'opinion-based' question, rather, I was intending to ask from a practical point of view, if there were advantages to choosing a 9V over any other solution (such as boosting AA batteries). Just wanted to make that clear!

Comment: Boost circuits can be noisy. Plus, they cost more to manufacture than "Batteries not included" labels.

Comment: "why are 9V batteries still used in the industry?", what industry would this be? Not my industry at least!

Comment: @Dampmaskin very true. Probably should have added about the way the industry is going, all about space saving and all that stuff, people are always trying to get more with less space. I was finding it difficult to find why people still chose to use 9V as I couldn't find any... electronic reasons

Comment: @pipe I mean electronics as a whole. Maybe industry was the wrong word.... You still see consumer goods powered by 9V batteries. "in the industry" was just the first phrase that came out of my head!

Comment: power electronics wasn't cheap or small or widely available in the past

Comment: I would say it is all about manufacturer legacy design inertia and extremely wide consumer availability.

Comment: If you use rechargeables then 6 AAs does not equal one PP3. NiMH PP3s tend to be 8.4V (7 cells) and some are even 9.6V, as opposed to 7.2V for 6xAA.

Comment: @Bob There's a lot of room for fudging voltages with anything intended to replace alkaline cells because during discharge each will  drop from ~1.5V to ~1V when the cell is dead.  a fixed 7.2 or 8.4v NiMH replacement is perfectly in spec.  9.6v is pushing the notional spec; OTOH the intrinsic voltage drop in alkaline cells means that any devices using them either need to be able to handle a relatively broad range of voltages directly or have some sort of voltage regulator.

Comment: +1 to @Dampmaskin. I want to provide an example: Electric guitars with active pickups (e.g. EMG81, Seymour Duncan Blackout) need a 9V battery for an opamp-based amplifier (yeah it's a noninverting amplifier with an output swing of 2Vpp max and an output impedance of 10k) inside the guitar. So, since guitarists/musicians don't want a noisy guitar tone --even if it is distorted heavily, single cell plus a boost circuit would be totally problematic --in terms of efficiency as well.

Comment: guitar effects *"stomp boxes"* still take 9v batteries.  at least some of them do.  it might be that many analog circuits still use discrete parts (like separate transistors, resistors, capacitors) and some of these BJTs might not work so well with a quiescent point lower than 3 or 4 volts.

Comment: A while ago I did a circuit that has +4V/-4V rails and maybe somewhat under 100µA current needs, I am not quite sure in terms of BOM costs and current requirements if feeding that from a 1.5V battery would give any advantage...

Answer (score 92, accepted):

First a AA is not a battery.. it's a cell. A battery is a "battery" of cells, i.e. more than one cell. A 9V battery contains six 1.5V cells. Rip one apart and see.

As for why we still use 9V batteries, it really is a matter of the design. The nice thing about 9V batteries is they give you a fairly wide operating voltage range during their life without being overly high a voltage. They also come in a really nice compact package that has a rather usable clip.

I would in no way recommend using one with a linear regulator to generate 5V though unless the current requirement on that 5V is very small. Better to design your circuitry using componentry that will work at the 9V directly.

It also really depends on the nature of your widget. If you have sensors or transducers that require larger voltages and it's battery operated, it's simpler and usually cheaper to go with a 9V battery.

One also has to consider the ramifications of boosting a lower voltage. By doing so you will introduce a lot of new problems not the least of which is the electromagnetic noise you will be adding and needing to deal with. Efficiency is also an issue.

But in the end, there is a lot of to and fro on the decision so this question really comes into the opinion ranks.

Comment: Another argument to make: A boost converter has <100% efficiency. In fact, the cheaper it is, the less likely it is to reach even 85% efficiency for e.g. a 1.5V -> 9V conversion. If you have the space, and you need 9V, why not get it directly?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Trevor. I did not intend this to be an 'opinion based' question, as I was trying to word it to ask what advantages are there and where would they be used rather than 'what is better, please discuss' which I could have done a better job of I suppose! I like the point about the sensors and transducers

Comment: I respectfully disagree with your first sentence.  A AA cell can be a battery.  A lot of devices only take one AA.

Comment: @trpt4him Also, they sell "AA batteries", not "battery refill AA cells".  Surely when discussing a circuit you can call the part with the AA's in it "the battery", but when discussing the objects you buy at a store and use to power that circuit, I think they are "batteries".

Comment: @trpt4him you have to look up what battery means. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/battery

Comment: @DarrenRinger just because it's a popular error.. does not make it right.

Comment: LOL @DarrenRinger u r right... I hate popularisms.... I could argue the English that Battery is a collective plural... but what would be the point

Comment: @Trevor I agree in principle, but definition 1b of the link you provided is "cell" - the words can be totally synonymous.  Words don't really have a single definition that must be enforced in all contexts, or am I misunderstanding your argument?

Comment: @DarrenRinger the issue comes when your device is powered by two or more AAs.. What you really have is "A Battery of AAs". "Two AA Batteries" does not make sense... We could argue it forever, I just recall getting yelled at by the electrical professor for using the wrong name.

Comment: In non-EE English, "AA battery" and "AA batteries" are phrases used by people and in advertisements (at least in the USA) every single day. "Two AA batteries not included" appears on so many packages. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery

Comment: I did look it up.  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/battery

Comment: I agree that a battery is an array of cell(s).  I see cells as a **component** of a battery; my car battery has 6.  I do not agree that the term "battery" cannot be used for single-cell devices, just as I do not agree an array requires 2 elements to declare.  A 1-cell battery is simply a cell which has additional finishing and packaging to render it fit for direct consumer use.

Comment: If I have 100 9V's, I have a "battery"?  Then, what if I remove 1/2 of them into two piles.  Do I have two "batteries" or two 1/2's of a battery?  It is kinda like a hole.  You can't dig 1/2 a hole.  Thus, "battery" is both singular and plural.  Usage of "batteries" is clear for anyone who reads it.

Comment: Why don't manufacturers integrate the 6 cells? Both kinds of 9v batteries I've seen (ones with 6 stacked rectangular cells, and those containing 6 AAAA cells) have a lot of empty space, and extra weight in the form of cell casings. Couldn't we get much better lifetime if we better used this space?

Comment: AA is not a battery or a cell.  It's a size.  Whether it is comprised of a single cell or multiple cells seems like an implementation detail that people *using* it don't need to care about as long as other observable characteristics remain the same.

Comment: 1s1p battery packs FTW.

Comment: Nobody is really wrong in this debate of *battery* vs *cell*. Strictly and historically speaking, a battery is a set of cells in series, and is primarily defined as such in the OED. In modern usage, the word *battery* has come to be broadened to include all single- and multi-cell devices, as is acknowledged in the OED's definition, reflecting the real-world usage of the word by just about every manufacturer of cells/batteries, makers of the products that require them, and the people who use them.

Comment: @DanielAustin but where will people direct their furious anger and rage? This is *literally* the most important problem anyways.

Comment: People - IT DOESN'T MATTER - jesus...

Comment: @NickT Fantastic use of "literally".  I'm glad that word now means essentially everything.

Comment: * literally everything. ^^

Comment: How many soldiers are in a "troop"?

Comment: For anyone who does not want to rip open a 9V battery, it looks like six pieces of PEZ candy - but DON'T EAT IT! [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkK3.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyD2E.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOoxu.jpg)

Comment: Battery vs. Cell. Battery **should be** a collection of cells, just as a flock is a collection of sheep. But people don't really follow such rules. I'm sort of in favour of the dictionary telling us how to speak (prescriptive), rather than reporting how we speak (descriptive). Otherwise, why do we need to learn English at school at all? However we talk would already be correct. I'm surprised "noocular" isn't now listed as a correct pronunciation for the word "nuclear" after several presidents of the USA [got it wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucular).

Comment: "contains six (size-AAA) 1.5V cells" - I don't think it's AAA size, those have diameter of 10.5 mm, and I can't see how you'd fit six of those into a 26.5 mm x 17.5 mm cross-section of PP3.

Comment: @DanMašek, thanks for pointing out that erroneous edit someone did....

Comment: Google defines a battery as one or more cells as does my copy of the Oxford English dictionary so I think its OK to talk about an 'AA' battery. This is not the [English language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site so can we stick to Electrical Engineering please.

Comment: Wouldn't a buck converter be fine with a 9VDC battery? The big concern I see with going down to 5VDC is if you're using an LDO regulator and burning off 4V*current as waste heat in the regulator.

Comment: In ancient times, Euclid did not consider 1 to be a number, because it was [not a multitude of ones](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5328/1872). Nowadays, of course, we know better.

Comment: As usual, it depends on context.  In a UPS room, there is a diesel generator, lines of glass boxes and an inverter.  All the glass boxes together are a 'battery'.  Each line of boxes is a 'string' and each box is a 'cell'.  In that context, the fact that each 'cell' is 12V and has six 2V lead-acid sub-units is irrelevant.  These terms are overloaded, like 'static' in C and  C++ ;)

Comment: AA is not a battery or a cell or a size.  It's a size specification.  Whether it is implemented exactly, slightly smaller, or slightly larger, the actual size is just an implementation detail of the specification.  People _using_ it don't actually care about how it's implemented as long as it works.

Comment: AA is not a battery, a cell, a size, or a size specification.  It stands for Alcoholics Anonymous for goodness sake.  You're all wrong.  Also I'm sorry I started this...

Comment: What about using a tiny SMPS?

Comment: Why is having a wide voltage range a good thing?

Comment: _"First a AA is not a battery.. it's a cell."_ is just unnecessary nitpicking. The question author asks for the reason for using 9V batteries, unsolicited and tangential schooling about terminology's minutiae. And [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery): _"[a] battery is a source of electric power consisting of **one or more** electrochemical cells with external connections for powering electrical devices."_ (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 103):

A 400mAh 9V battery will last a year with a 40µA current draw.

Now consider a smoke detector. It is low power analog circuitry, most likely drawing less than the 40µA figure above. If you wanted to power it from a boost converter and AAs, then you'd need a converter with very low idle current.

But... when there is fire, now you need quite a bit of power, and enough volts, to drive the piezo loudspeaker. These need voltage. 9V is louder than 3V.

So your very low idle current DC-DC converter also needs to output high current if needed.

You also need to be able to measure state of charge accurately on the AAs.

All this will cost more than the difference between 9V and 2AA. And remember, the customer pays for the replacement batteries, not the manufacturer!

Comment: But surely, the really best design would be to have the detection circuit operate at only 1.5 V without any boosting, and only in case of a fire switch on the high-power boost converter to drive the speaker?

Comment: A few (10? maybe 20?) years ago I'd have said "because they are there". Early transistor radios were made to run on 9 V because of the germanium transistors they used. So "9 volt" batteries were very very common, easy to find in stores. Not so much any more. My local convenience stores stopped carrying them quite a while ago.

Comment: Not sure it matters but all the smoke detectors I've purchased in the last 10 years run on AA batteries.

Comment: @JimmyJames: exactly the opposite of my experience. All the smoke detectors I bought in the last 10 years run on 9V batteries. Even the backup for the powered ones was 9V.

Comment: Yeah, here in France it's all 9V...

Comment: @MartinArgerami It used to always be 9V in my experience.  It's a fairly recent change.  In the US there is a big push to reduce the number of smoke detectors that are left without power.  Often in rentals the residents will just pull out the battery when it starts beeping and leave it like that.  Since most everyone keeps AAs on hand, it's less of a burden to replace them.  The ones I am buying are also more 'advanced' in they they also detect CO and/or are interconnected wirelessly which could be a factor.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The booster is yet another thing to fail, by no means the most complicated part of your design; maybe not something you want in a safety device. In the basic design, the smoke detector is just a battery, the detecting circuit, one relay (probably a transistor-based) and one speaker. And put aside, a voltage check for low batteries. All parts are essential in that you can't be without them. This means the design is as easy as possible.

Comment: If a smoke detector has a relay, I think it could have two SMPSs, one of which is designed for low quiescent current and another relay-powered one that is designed for high peak current (and thus high quiescent current, which doesn't matter because it's relay powered).

Comment: Good points. Simple design is more robust. @leftaroundabout Good idea, but better to design the main circuit to draw fewer amps from a higher-voltage battery. Also imagine a WiFi module that wakes up every hour to make a measurement and send the results. 2x CR2032 would easily beat a larger cell with a boost circuit.

Comment: @JimmyJames: People would be less likely to leave detectors without power if there were an easy way to shut off the low-battery chirping for 12 hours or so without disabling the detector.  If the detector starts chirping at 2am and the store isn't going to open until 9am, what is someone supposed to do?

Comment: I like this answer more than the accepted one

Comment: It might be the quality of the detectors I buy :-) but all of them had a simple mechanical latch that made it impossible to put it back into its holder if the battery compartment was empty.

Answer (score 40):

Boost circuits have a quiescent current; some energy is wasted simply by having the boost converter. They also get very inefficient at low duty cycles.

So if you have a circuit that *usually* draws a very small current but occasionally needs to draw more, it's difficult to address that with a single boost converter.

The main users of 9V batteries are things like smoke alarms and multimeters that exactly fit this use case: low current some or almost all of the time. If you expect the battery life to be less than, say, 3 years with a 9V battery then it may be a poor choice.

You can see this in that almost anything that has a radio - toys, remote controls, etc - will be using either several AA or rechargeable Li of some sort.

Boost converters aren't free either, they cost parts and space.

(The design that allows cheap wall clocks to run off a *single* AA battery is quite neat, and I'd like to see a good reverse engineering of it.)

Comment: Nothing special about 1.5v electromechanical clocks, really. Here's an ancient datasheet which is pretty detailed: https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/197819/ICM7038.pdf

Comment: In addition, boost converters tend to be much more noisy than step-down converters.

Answer (score 35):

My multimeter uses a 9V battery and maybe draws about 10mA to function. It is very accurate.

If it is powered by a 3V battery, the average current will be 40mA with a 75% efficiency. However the surge current have to go up 80mA, thru an inductor. Basically the trace, battery wire and the inductor now act as an antenna giving off energy to my sensitive components inside my multimeter.

Then my readings will jump around and I'll curse and swear for buying a 2 AA battery powered meter.

Comment: Very good answer. Like that you used a practical example. Thank you

Comment: My multimeter uses 2 AA batteries and works just fine, yet is even one of the most accurate ones. So, if the circuit is designed to work with low voltages it works - question remains why they used the 9V in the multimeter. Probably because they have done it like that for ages and never change a running system if you don't have to.

Comment: The newer accurate models now uses 4 X AA. There are some models that uses just 2 X AA but did not boost to higher voltage. The downside is some function are not included.

Answer (score 19):

I used to have an old programmable calculator powered by a bunch of AA batteries. The annoying thing about it was that is would easily reboot if you shook it. This never happens to my multimeter running from a 9V battery.

Also, electronics which needs about 5V is usually powered by 3xAA batteries, not by a 9V one. Having a few extra volts does simplify a lot of designs, especially with older opamps which could not provide rail-to-rail output. This is less of an issue nowadays, when most parts have a 3.3V version.

Comment: Don't blame the batteries if your battery compartment is poorly designed.   I have exactly the same problem on my VX-8 radio, and it uses an encased rechargeable battery pack.  Just touch the radio and it reboots.

Comment: @richard1941 Battery design does have an effect on battery compartment design, and AA cells rely on the same structural parts for mechanical support and electrical contact.

Comment: Good point about the 9V battery connector. The battery can easily hang loose by the connected cables.

Answer (score 15):

PP3 batteries are fine with many meter chips, for example. In many cases the total energy per dollar may not be all that important- if the battery lasts for a year or three it is good enough, and they can save a bit of money with circuitry. Another example would be a backup battery- shelf life is more important than energy density.

You will often see button cells used, which hold even less energy and can be breathtakingly expensive (or quite cheap) in applications where total energy consumed over a reasonable battery life is not that high. Where more energy is required, rechargeable Li-ion cells are more common.

I don't think that many **new** applications, even in consumer goods, use 9V batteries- but there will be older devices (and older designs) out there for decades to come.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, You are correct in saying that not many new applications use them, although a small few do. This does seem to support that it may be better not to use them do you not think? You are very correct in saying if it lasts long enough, then it's good enough. I suppose it would be cheaper to use one of them with something drawing a very small amount of current, so that is a good point to make

Comment: @MCG Yes, I would suggest it is probably best not to use them in new designs.

Comment: One type of unit that uses them still is a guitar effects pedal. Seems like a good idea when you want a high enough voltage to supply circuitry to deal with line level and have some headroom while not wanting a noisy switcher.

Comment: DeBosco--- I have exactly the effects pedal you are talking about (Boss PS2, makes me sound almost as good as Rod Piazza).   I always suspected that the designers were in a conspiracy with the battery manufacturers.

Comment: I think you mean PP3 batteries - a 9V battery measuring 49x27x18mm. The last time I saw a PP9 (9V, 81x66x52mm) outside of its retail packaging was over 20 years ago. It powered a discrete transistor AM radio. I've never seen anything that large in a meter. The PP9 *has* largely been replaced by 6xAA batteries (or with modern lower voltage circuits, 4xAA batteries)  but the PP3 remains popular for those small applications whose voltage requirements would need more than 2 AAA cells.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt You're right, of course, edited to say PP3.

Answer (score 10):

Considerations of battery selection may include propensity to leak, supportability of a product, maximum current demand, and recycling issues.

- Leakage of AA cells:  In electronic equipment battery leakage can be a big problem unless special design features are incorporated in the battery holder to avoid corrosion.  Alas, gold contacts are expen$ive.  I do not know if 9 volt batteries are more or less likely to leak, but if you can find out, that might influence your selection decision for equipment that must go unattended for years.  I have some gear wrecked by leakage of Duracell AA alkalines.
- Supportability: Perhaps at some time in the future 9 volt batteries will become as available as Kodachrome is today.   In that case, any equipment may require replacement.   This may be a marketing, not an engineering decision: your marketing people may like the idea that the product becomes useless in a few years and will need to be replaced.
- Maximum Current Demand: The maximum current and power are governed by Thevenin and Norton.  The battery acts as if it is a perfect voltage source in series with a resistor.  The voltage and resistance are variable according to the internal condition of the battery.  And the maximum power available is at a load current that drops half the battery voltage across that internal resistance.  Some lab work may be necessary to decide the best battery for your application, depending on peak power demand.
- Recycling Issues: For environmental reason$ only, of course, I like to recycle my AA Duracells by the unorthodox means of recharging them and using them again.  I find that the recharged AA Duracell comes back to full voltage, but has a higher internal resistance that prevents my radio from playing at maximum volume. The recharged cells also have a shorter life.  But I get many more hours of play at lower volume.   With a 9 volt battery, you may have only one dead cell out of six, so recharging to restore the one may degrade the other five by overcharging.  Some lab experimentation would be required to determine the best way to go.   And whatever the result of your experiments, a change in the battery supplier or the supplier's manufacturing process might invalidate your results.

So, good luck.  In engineering their might not be a right or wrong answer.  Most decisions are a compromise between competing issues.

Comment: I like your first point about the leakage. I have had AA batteries leak in some products too in the past

Comment: 9V batteries are probably less likely to leak since the total volume of electrolyte released from a leaky cell is usually pretty small, and most 9V batteries have enough empty space inside that they could contain the leakage from one or two cells.

Answer (score 9):

Boost regulators (and the engineers to design them) haven't always been cheap or small. Consequently, there is plenty of equipment in the market that uses either an unregulated 9v rail or a linear regulator. Smoke alarms and multimeters are a couple of examples - redesigning would cost money and wouldn't substantially reduce the BOM cost or increase marketable functionality.

*(Now, a smoke alarm that recharged a supercapacitor using the alpha emissions from the source and never needed a battery change would have a market advantage - not sure if the laws of physics allow...)*

Comment: I think a source that emits that much energy would be illegal to sell to average people.

Comment: 12 VDC * 8 mA (piezo speaker) / 4e-6 W (nuclear pacemaker battery) / 60 / 60 = 6.67 hours to beep for 1 second?

Comment: I think the amount of material in a nuclear pacemaker wouldn't be licensed for an uncontrolled device, which is one reason they aren't used any more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betacel. The obvious (if boring) energy source for a smoke alarm would be a solar cell or mains pickup coil.

Comment: Or a thermal power generator: installed on the ceiling, it will feel a temperature difference between the inside air and the attic.  I recall having a problem where the heat detectors were sounding false alarms because the attic was heating the ceiling!

Comment: I like your idea for a power source, but it should only be allowed for above average people like us.

Comment: I like the peltier effect idea. Alternatively, a molten salt battery initiated by the fire could produce ample energy for a beeper - albeit possibly itself contributing to the flamage.

Answer (score 9):

When you try to design ultra low noise equipment, a quiet linear regulator on a 9V battery will beat almost any DC-DC converter which invariably will have some switching noise (either in the output, or emitted). That certainly was the rule of thumb in our astrophysics department (admittedly, that's an old argument that may have been overtaken by reality).

Others have pointed out the advantage (in terms of standby current) of using 9V in a system with a low power need but the requirement of long battery life / high instant power (e.g. fire alarms). But you are right - if power density is the main criterion, the old PP9 is not a terrific choice. And that's why you don't see them in many flashlights, for example.

Answer (score 9):

A couple of points not addressed in other answers:

Your weight comparison is fair, but I think direct volume-volume comparision is unfair, because usually there is some space wasted when packing round objects. The space occupied by the cuboid containing an AA cell is about 10.5cm3. Multiply that by PI/4 to get the cylinder volume and we get close to the 8.1cm3 in your table.

With a PP3 9V battery, you are paying to have 6 tiny 1.5V cells (smaller than AAA) supplied in a convenient package. It is this "unnecessary" packaging that adds the extra weight and bulk. The applications where these batteries are used are small enough that the cost for this packaging often is not perceived to matter.

If an equipment manufacturer (who normally sells his goods "battery not included") is choosing between using 2xAA cells plus voltage converter or 1xPP3 cell, **he has to consider not only the additional cost of the converter, but also the battery connector.** PP3 batteries have a very neat off the shelf connector that clips on one end, while individual cells need a proper battery holder integrated into the product, to grab the battery at both ends. Given the consumer rarely considers the cost of batteries when purchasing equipment, that gives the manufacturer two reasons to go for the PP3.

Comment: I've disassembled some Radio Shack brand 9V batteries in the 1970s and found that they contained a stack of six almost-rectangular cells, rather than the usual six long skinny ones.  I don't know if any modern 9V batteries are made that way, though.

Comment: I may be a rare consumer, then. 9V batteries tend to be a deal-breaker for me when selecting a device: they're still unreasonably expensive compared to AA. For about the same price per volt (CA$20 for 40 AAs or CA$13 for 4 9Vs), I get about 4.5 times the number of Joules with AAs, if the numbers in the table are correct.